# Mixing two .fla projects

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have made a `.fla` project and I want to put another `.fla` project file into it. The second `.fla` project contain some code (actions) about page flipping. When I want to export the project, this error appears:

> Symbol 'frame3', Layer 'Loader', Frame 1, Line 223    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderHint.
>
> Symbol 'frame3', Layer 'Loader', Frame 1, Line 223    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method SliderHint.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when this happens because you do not copy over the scripts that were brought over from FLA-A to FLA-B, also look for any external references from FLA-A in the event that both FLA files live in different directories.